# asp:textbox calling asp:button handler on text change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have the most bizarre problem happening ... I'm controlling a menu edit page and I have a series of controls, an asp:textbox with the numeric ID of the menu being worked on, flanked by - and + buttons to decrement and increment the ID.  The user can type a new index in the textbox, or use the buttons.  Easy peasy, right?

Here's the ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Button id="menuDown" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="DownClick" Text="-" /> 
Menu # <asp:textbox runat="server" MaxLength="5" Columns="3" id="tbMenuId" />
<asp:Button id="menuUp" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="UpClick" Text="+" />
```

There's a CompareValidator further down the page ensuring a non-negative, numeric entry.

Over in my code behind, my Page_Load pulls the value out of the textbox without problems:

```
Try
   menuId = Integer.Parse(tbMenuId.Text)
Catch
   menuId = 0
   tbMenuId.Text = "0"
End Try
```

This works great (with ONE caveat) — every time I change the menu ID via the textbox, after the Page_Load method pulls the new value out of the text box perfectly, the DownClick handler gets called, decrementing the desired ID.

So far, the ONLY way I've managed to have the requested menu appear is to eliminate the two asp:Button controls. Eliminating only the menuDown button causes the UpClick handler to get called.

I *had* an OnTextChanged="..." attribute on the asp:Textbox control, but that handler NEVER got called and didn't seem necessary anyway, so I pulled it.

I cannot help but think the two behaviors must be connected.

Anyone understand WHY this is happening?

Comment: Have you set autopostback to true for the textbox.  What i feel is that your form is getting posted on the textchange event.

Comment: I'm not explicitly setting autopostback, and learn.microsoft.com claims the default is false, but I'll specify ... and no difference.

I have eliminated the two buttons I mentioned before to avoid this behavior, but now when I hit enter in the text box after changing the value, the Page_Load code is run, then the handler for the asp:button at the bottom of the page. <smdh>

Seems I can't win for losing ... if I have an asp:button on the same page as my asp:textbox, the button's handler fires when I change data in the textbox.

Comment: One more experiment from last night I forgot to report on:  I added a asp:button id="dunsel" with a do-nothing handler to absorb the click.  Works as long as dunsel is visible, but if I make dunsel invisible, the handler for the button at the bottom of the page fires instead.

Answer (score 0):

This qualifies as hacky work-around, rather than a fix, but it does let me proceed forward until this behavior can be explained.

The OnTextChanged event is firing the way it's supposed to now (not sure what I did wrong the first time) so, I used it to implement the hackiest of hacks ...

```
Protected Property hackyFlag As Boolean ' Suppress button click (true) after text change
```

' ... value in session variable

```
Protected Sub tbMenuId_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Integer.TryParse(tbMenuId.Text, menuId)
    hackyFlag = True
End Sub

Protected Sub DownClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If hackyFlag Then : hackyFlag = False : Return : End If
    If menuId > 0 Then menuId -= 1
    tbMenuId.Text = menuId
End Sub
```

Gross, hacky, and disgusting ... but it works.  :-)  The button handler is still being called incorrectly, but now it's smart enough to do what I want instead of what the framework is telling it to do.

Still open to better answers and/or explanations as to why this is happening on this page and hasn't happened on any other. ( knock on wood )